# statsmodels - printing summary of ARMA fit throws error

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I want to fit an ARMA(p,q) model to simulated data, `y`,  and check the effect of different estimation methods on the results. However, fitting a model to the same object like so

```
model = tsa.ARMA(y,(1,1))
results_mle = model.fit(trend='c', method='mle', disp=False)
results_css = model.fit(trend='c', method='css', disp=False)
```

and printing the results

```
print result_mle.summary()
print result_css.summary()
```

generates the following error

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 1572, in summary
smry.add_table_params(self, alpha=alpha, use_t=False)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\iolib\summary.py", line 885, in add_table_params
use_t=use_t)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\iolib\summary.py", line 475, in summary_params
exog_idx]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

If, instead, I do this

```
model1 = tsa.ARMA(y,(1,1))
model2 = tsa.ARMA(y,(1,1))
result_mle = model1.fit(trend='c',method='css-mle',disp=False) 
print result_mle.summary()

result_css = model2.fit(trend='c',method='css',disp=False)
print result_css.summary()
```

no error occurs. Is that supposed to be or a Bug that should be fixed?

BTW the ARMA process I generated as follows

```
from __future__ import division

import statsmodels.tsa.api as tsa
import numpy as np
# generate arma
a = -0.7
b = -0.7
c = 2
s = 10
y1 = np.random.normal(c/(1-a),s*(1+(a+b)**2/(1-a**2)))
e = np.random.normal(0,s,(100,))

y = [y1]
for t in xrange(e.size-1):
    arma = c + a*y[-1] + e[t+1] + b*e[t] 
    y.append(arma)

y = np.array(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could report this as a bug, even though it looks like a consequence of the current design.

Some attributes of the model change when the estimation method is changed, which should in general be avoided. Since both results instances access the same model, the older one is inconsistent with it in this case.

http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/pitfalls.html#repeated-calls-to-fit-with-different-parameters

In general, statsmodels tries to keep all parameters that need to change the model in the `model.__init__` and not as arguments in `fit`, and attach the outcome of fit and results to the Results instance. 
However, this is not followed everywhere, especially not in older models that gained new options along the way.

`trend` is an example that is supposed to go into the `ARMA.__init__` because it is now handled together with the exog (which is an ARMAX model), but wasn't in pure ARMA. The estimation method belongs in `fit` and should not cause problems like these.

Aside: There is a helper function to simulate an ARMA process that uses scipy.signal.lfilter and should be much faster than an iteration loop in Python.